# scraping data from multiple sites in webdriver selenium

Tags: python, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to **scrape** data from multiple urls and saved them in a csv, with the code i have i can open all 3 sites but only it saves the data from the last link with all its pages included

```
data = {}
for j, url in enumerate(urls):
    driver.get(url)
for page in range(100):
    data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gs_ai_t")
    with open('pages.csv','a',newline='') as s:
        csv_writer =writer(s)
        for i in range(len(data)):
            nombre = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gs_ai_name")         
            n = nombre[i].text.replace(',','')
            csv_writer.writerow([n])
           
    button_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_locators)))
    button_link.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some re-arranging and slight changes to your code. See notes at the bottom of the answer.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as W
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common import exceptions as SE
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from csv import writer

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=" ")
chrome_path=r"C:\Users\gvste\Desktop\proyecto\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

urls = ['https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&authuser=2&org=17388732461633852730', 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&authuser=2&org=8337597745079551909', 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&authuser=2&org=6030355530770144394']

# this is the xpath for NEXT button *ENABLED*!
button_locators = "//button[@class='gs_btnPR gs_in_ib gs_btn_half gs_btn_lsb gs_btn_srt gsc_pgn_pnx']"
wait_time = 3

wait = W(driver, wait_time)

# prepare the csv file
with open('pages.csv', 'w', newline='') as s:
    csv_writer = writer(s)
    headers = ['Nombre','Universidad', 'Mail', 'Citas', 'Tags']
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)


for url in urls:
    data = {}
    driver.get(url)

    button_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_locators)))

    # while the ENABLED button exists...
    while button_link:
        try:
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'gsc_sa_ccl')))  #wait for data parent element to load
            data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gs_ai_t")

            with open('pages.csv','a',newline='') as s:
                csv_writer =writer(s)
                for i in range(len(data)):
                    nombre = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gs_ai_name")
                    universidad = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gs_ai_aff")
                    mail = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gs_ai_eml")
                    citas = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gs_ai_cby")
                    tags = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gs_ai_int")
                    link = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('gs_ai_pho')

                    n = nombre[i].text.replace(',', '')
                    u = universidad[i].text.replace(',', '')
                    m = mail[i].text.replace(',', '')
                    c = citas[i].text.replace(',', '')
                    t = tags[i].text.replace(',', '')
                    l = link[i].get_attribute('href')

                    csv_writer.writerow([n, u, m, c, t, l])

            button_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, button_locators)))
            button_link.click()

        # when the ENABLED button no longer exists on the page Selenium WebDriverWait will throw a TimeoutException,
        # in which case break the loop and move on to the next url
        except SE.TimeoutException:
            print(f'Last page parsed for url {url}')
            break

driver.quit()
```

**Notes:**

- Avoid relying on full xpath. See updated `button_locators` and keep
  in mind you will have a special case once you reached the last page
  of each url.
- For each url, create a new `data` dictionary and collect details as
  long as there is a "Next" button matching the `button_locators`
  xpath.
- Do this in a `try-except` block as the button will not exist on the
  last page.
- No changes to your .csv append code.
- Note the Selenium `exceptions` import (SE) required for the `except`
  block.

Comment: It works perfectly thank you so much... 
Also, any tips about the best way to search the urls? in this case there were only 3 so there's no a big deal, but I want to do this for, like, at least 30 other urls... I have a list of urls in a Google Sheet for the moment, can I get the urls from there (I haven't been able to get the urls from there so far)?, Or do I get them from another place/format?
Thanks again!

Comment: The ideal situation would be if Google Scholar had an API to get data from in `json` format. But they don't provide one unfortunately. There are some other solutions that try to go around the lack of API e.g. [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-api) or [scholarly](https://pypi.org/project/scholarly/), although I can't say they would resolve your exact requitement. I have tried neither, but I think they're worth explorying.

Comment: Yeah I really wish they have an API, I get why they don't have it tho but still, thanks anyway, i'll check those options out.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting `data` when you fetch the urls:

```
data = {}
for j, url in enumerate(urls):
    driver.get(url)
```

You still get the last page because the driver is on the last page when you start parsing:

```
data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gs_ai_t")
```

**Solution:**
Instantiates a webdriver and fetch the url for each of the urls and make a dictionary out of it.

```
data = {i : webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path).get(url) for i, url in enumerate(urls)}
```

**Another Solution:**
Start parsing the data as soon as the webdriver fetch the url:

```
for j, url in enumerate(urls):
    driver.get(url)

    wait = W(driver, wait_time)
    time.sleep(4)

    for page in range(100):
        data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("gs_ai_t")
        ...
```

Comment: the second solution works but it only open the first page of the site, click the button once, and then changes to the other site (so i can see 2 pages of each site) and it saves only the data of the first page of each site in the csv